# Knitr & Rmarkdown docx tables

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, docx, pandoc

When using `knitr` and `rmarkdown` together to create a word document you can use an existing document to style the output.

For example in my yaml header:

```
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: style.docx
    fig_caption: TRUE
```

within this style i have created a default table style - the goal here is to have the `kable` table output in the correct style.

When I knit the word document and use the style.docx the tables are not stylized according to the table.

Using the style inspector has not been helpful so far, unsure if the default table style is the incorrect style to modify.

Example Code:

````
```{r kable}
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(n)
out <- lm(y ~ x)
library(knitr)
kable(summary(out)$coef, digits=2, caption = "Test Captions")
```
````

I do not have a stylized document I can upload for testing unfortunately.

TL;DR: Want to stylise table output from rmarkdown and knitr automatically (via kable)

**Update:** So far I have found that changing the 'compact' style in the docx will alter the text contents of the table automatically - but this does not address the overall table styling such as cell colour and alignment.

**Update 2:** After more research and creation of styles I found that `knitr` seems to have no problem accessing paragraph styles. However table styles are not under that style category and don't seem to apply in my personal testing.

**Update 3:** Dabbled with the `ReporteRs` package - whilst it was able to produce the tables as a desired the syntax required to do so is laborious. Much rather the style be automatically applied.

**Update 4:** You cannot change TableNormal style, nor does setting a Table Normal style work. The XML approach is not what we are looking for. I have a VBA macro that will do the trick, just want to remove that process if possible.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `kable` as `pandoc` does the conversion from markdown to docx. You can try creating a `TableNormal` table style in the reference docx file.

Comment: To @daroczig's point, this is essentially a `pandoc` problem and possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858598/add-styling-rules-in-pandoc-tables-for-odt-docx-output-table-borders. That post is only concerned with borders, but I suspect the underlying xml could be hacked to get more elaborate formatting...

Comment: I had a similar problem with styles of the reference_docx in general. Perhaps this is the same issue? https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/668

Comment: @zacdav this is after the fact but if you are able to I would highly recommend using `knitr` with pdflatex. Latex takes a bit more time to figure out but there is a ton of info of questions already asked. Usually whatever you need to do has already been completed and you copy/paste.

Comment: @Prevost this was specifically done in word because clients will want that format.

Answer (score 23):

This is essentially a combination of [the answer that recommends `TableNormal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34148111/2706569), [this post on rmarkdown.rstudio.com](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html) and my own experiments to show how to use a `TableNormal` style to customize tables like those generated by `kable`:

**RMD**:

````
---
output:
  word_document
---

```{r}
knitr::kable(cars)
```
````

- Click "Knit Word" in RStudio. → The document opens in Word, without any custom styles yet.
- In that document (*not* in a new document), add the required styles. [This article](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html) explains the basics. Key is not to apply *direct styles* but to modify the *styles*. See [this article on support.office.com on Style basics in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Style-basics-in-Word-d382f84d-5c38-4444-98a5-9cbb6ede1ba4#bm1).
- Specifically, to style a table you need to add a *table style*. My version of Word is non-English, but according to the article linked above table styles are available via "the Design tab, on the Table Tools contextual tab".
- Choose `TableNormal` as style name and define the desired styles. In my experiments most styles worked, however some did not. (Adding a color to the first column and making the first row bold was no problem; highlighting every second row was ignored.) The last screenshot in this answer illustrates this step.
- Save the document, e.g. as `styles.docx`.
- Modify the header in the RMD file to use the reference DOCX (see [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html#style_reference); don't screw up the indentation – took me 10 minutes find this mistake):

  ```
  ---
  output:
    word_document:
      reference_docx: styles.docx
  ---
  ```
- Knit to DOCX again – the style should now be applied.

Following the steps I described above yields this output:

[image: Output]

And here a screenshot of the table style dialog used to define `TableNormal`. Unfortunately it is in German, but maybe someone can provide an English version of it:

[image: Table Style]

---

As this does not seem to work for most users (anyone but me …), I suggest we test this systematically. Essentially, there are 4 steps that can go wrong:

- Wrong RMD (unlikely).
- Differences in the initially generated DOCX.
- Differences in how the `TableNormal` style is saved in the DOCX.
- Differences in how the reference DOCX is used to format the final DOCX.

I therefore suggest using the same minimal RMD posted above ([full code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/v3HGSgsE)) to find out where the results start do differ:

- My [initially generated DOCX](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw4KQj8EqSdEaTVqU1NUckh5bFU).
- The same document with `TableNormal` added: [reference.docx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw4KQj8EqSdEMDJPa1Z2RFdRaTA)
- The [final document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw4KQj8EqSdEbXZPaVVmZkktd1U).

The three files are generated on the following system: Windows 7 / R 3.3.0 / RStudio 0.99.896 / pandoc 1.15.2 / Office 2010.

I get the same results on a system with Windows 7 / R 3.2.4 / RStudio 0.99.484 / pandoc 1.13.1 / Office 2010.

I suppose the most likely culprits are the pandoc and the Office versions. Unfortunately, I cannot test other configurations at the moment. Now it would be interesting to see the following: For users where it does not work, what happens …

- … if you start from my [initial.docx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw4KQj8EqSdEaTVqU1NUckh5bFU)?
- If that does not work, what if you use my [reference.docx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw4KQj8EqSdEMDJPa1Z2RFdRaTA) as reference document?
- If nothing works, are there eye-catching differences in the generated XML files (inside the DOCX container)? Please share your files and exact version information.

With a number of users running these tests it should be possible to find out what is causing the problems.

Comment: This does not work on English versions on Word it seems, if you had noticed update 4 I had already tried exactly this. I've since tried it again with completely new documents following the answer you provided and it does not work.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9p9Rsa-Y-hRNVJDZDlCWDNDbWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @zacdav I noticed update 4, but assumed that you were doing something wrong. Interestingly, if I use the DOCX file you uploaded to Google Drive as reference DOCX, I get [this output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw4KQj8EqSdEWGFsTm5VMnhGbWM) (red background in first column). So the reference document you created works on my system – very strange. I'll check this with a different version of Word as soon as I can; currently I'm using Office 2010.

Comment: Yea that is interesting. I have tried this on 4 systems so far and none have worked. All using office 365 however.

Comment: That does not work neither on my computer (Office 2016). In case I don't receive any other answer you will be awarded the bounty for effort and level of details.

Comment: @EricLecoutre Hopefully, we'll be able to figure out what is causing these problems. If it's actually a matter of Office versions, then this could be worth a bug report to `pandoc`.

Comment: I just tried to view the documents with LibreOffice and can confirm it still does not work.

Comment: @EricLecoutre and zacdav: Updated the answer. Let's see whether we can figure out what is causing the problems. Unfortunately, I will have only very limited time to support this process (my master's thesis is due in 10 days – this has priority …).

Comment: Guy: I hope you the best for your master thesis: resistance to final rush , good presentation and nice results!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eric!

Comment: None of your supplied documents generate the desired result on the computers I tried with office 365 / English Version

Comment: @zacdav What a pity ... Can you upload one of the non-working DOCX files?

Comment: Ive already uploaded mine prior and you have all yours. Try opening them on an English version.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if anyone has tried this with success and what language/system they used.
I've yet to see this work.

Answer (score 7):

This was actually [a known issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3275). Fortunately, it was solved in v2.0 or later releases of `pandoc`.

And I have tested the newer version, and found that there is a newly-added hidden style called "**Table**". Following @CL.'s suggestions to change "Table" style in `reference.docx` will be okay now.

In addition, look at this entry of `pandoc`'s v2.0 release notes:

> Use `Table` rather than `Table Normal` for table style ([#3275](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3275)). `Table Normal` is the default table style and can’t be modified.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2021, I could *not* get any of the other suggested answers to work.

However, I did discover the [`{officedown}`](https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown) package, which, amongst other things, supports the styling of tables in `.docx` documents. You can install `{officedown}` with `remotes::install_github("davidgohel/officedown")`

To use `{officedown}` to render `.Rmd` to `.docx` you must replace

```yaml
output:
  word_document
```

in your document header with

```yaml
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document
```

In addition to this the `{officedown}` package must be loaded in your `.Rmd`.

As with the `word_document` output format, `{officedown}` allows us to use styles and settings from template documents, again with the `reference_docx` parameter.

With a reference document `styles.docx`, a minimal example `.Rmd` may look like:

````
---
date: "2038-01-19"
author: "The Reasonabilists"
title: "The end of time as we know it"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: styles.docx
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
# Don't forget about me: I'm important!
library("officedown")
```
````

`{officedown}` allows us to go one step further and specify the name of the table style to use in the document's front matter. This table style could be [a custom style we created](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563?redirectsourcepath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fstyle-basics-in-word-d382f84d-5c38-4444-98a5-9cbb6ede1ba4#bm1) in `styles.docx`, or it could be one of Word's in-built styles you prefer.

Let's say we created a style `My Table`:

[image]

We could tell `{officedown}` to use this table style in our front matter as:

```yaml
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: styles.docx
    tables:
      style: My Table
```

Putting this altogether, knitting the minimal `.Rmd`:

````
---
date: "2038-01-19"
author: "The Reasonabilists"
title: "The end of time as we know it"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: styles.docx
    tables:
      style: My Table
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
# Don't forget about me: I'm important!
library(officedown)
```

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

Resulting in a `.docx` document which looks like:

[image]

Comment: anyone know whether officedown can generate gt() formatted tables in word?

Answer (score 2):

`TableNormal` doesn't work for me too.

On my Dutch version of Word 2016 (Office 365), I found out that I could markup tables with the style **`Compact`**.

Input (`refdoc.docx` contains the `Compact` style):

```
---
title: "Titel"
subtitle:  "Ondertitel"
author: "`r Sys.getenv('USERNAME')`"
output:
  word_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    fig_width: 6.5
    fig_height: 3.5
    fig_caption: true
    reference_docx: "refdoc.docx"
---
```

And RMarkdown:

````
# Methoden {#methoden}
```{r}
kable(cars)
```
````

Output:

[image: img]

Comment: I can confirm that this also works in the English version of Word 2016. A small problem with this solution is that bullets are also formatted using the 'Compact' style. I have not found a way to format tables and bullets independently.

Comment: Hmm, maybe we should knit a new default document and merge these styles with our own reference style file. I’ll have a look again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a `reference_docx: style.docx` which has "Table" style in it. (see @Liang Zhang's explanation and links above).

1. Create a basis reference document using pandoc ([source](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3275#issuecomment-595242853)). In command line (or cmd.exe on Windows) run:
   `pandoc -o custom-reference.docx --print-default-data-file reference.docx`
2. In this newly created `reference.docx` file, find the table created (a basic 1 row table with a caption).
3. While the table is selected, click "Table Design" and find "Modify Table Style":

[image]

4. Modify the style of the table as you wish and use this reference document in your RMD document (see the first answer by @CL.).

Using this reference document, you can also change the table and figure caption styles.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my word output to use a default table style that I defined in a reference .docx.

Instead of 'TableNormal', the table style it defaulted to was 'Table'.

I discovered this by knitting an rmarkdown with a kable.

```
---
date: "December 1, 2017"
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: Template.docx
---
`r knitr::kable(source)`
```

Then I took a look at that generated document's XML to see what style it had defaulted to.

```
require(XML)

docx.file <- "generated_doc.docx"

## unzip the docx converted by Pandoc
system(paste("unzip", docx.file, "-d temp_dir"))
document.xml <- "temp_dir/word/document.xml"

doc <- xmlParse(document.xml)
tblStyle <- getNodeSet(xmlRoot(doc), "//w:tblStyle")

tblStyle
```

I defined the 'Table' style to put some color and borders in the reference docx. This works for one standard table style throughout the document, I haven't found a way to use different styles throughout.

This stayed true even after I opened the reference doc and edited it.