# Unable to create table using ggplot() in Rmarkdown for word

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am trying to create a table like the following image:
[image]

I want this table to be created from rmarkdown to a word file.
I have tried to create it using knitr. But it is not being created.

```
 value_1 <- 0.178
 value_1 <- 0.235

 table <-
    matrix(c(value_1, value_2), ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE)
 rownames(table) <- c("Variable_1", "Variable_2")
 colnames(table) <- c("Value")
 table_final <- as.table(table)
```

Now, when I use `knitr::kable(table_final)`, in word file I do not see the table, but when I knit in HTML the table comes but there are no column separators.

Is there any way I can create the table as shown in the image using a word document as output in rmarkdown?

Also can we use `ggplot()`?

Comment: Does following an e.g. like this one help? https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html e.g. the `Tables using kable()` section

Comment: Yes I have already tried that. But I am not getting table borders with that. I have a large table and this is just a glimpse of how I want the table.

Comment: In order to customize word document output, you'll need to use `reference_docx:`. This post has a summary https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671868/knitr-rmarkdown-docx-tables/37890832#37890832